# Calculation of the rate of transition of the Hydrogen electron from $|2lm\rangle$ to ground state

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, hydrogen, photon-emission, fermis-golden-rule

This is how it was calculated in my book:

We take the electromagnetic field to be part of the system. The initial state of the system is the direct product $|2,l,m\rangle \times |0\rangle$. $|0 \rangle$ is the ground state of the EM field. The final state of the system is $|1,0,0\rangle \times |\vec{k} \lambda \rangle$. $|\vec{k} \lambda \rangle$ being the state of the EM field with 1 photon in the mode $|\vec{k} \lambda\rangle$ (I think)

The Hamiltonian used is :

$$H_0+\vec{A} \cdot \vec{P}$$

Then we use the Fermi golden rule with the given initial and final states.

1. Wasn't the Fermi Golden rule derived for the Hamiltonian $H_0+H_1e^{i\omega t}$? Then how does it apply to the present problem with a time independent Hamiltonian?
2. I'm not sure what the operator $\vec{A}$ is. I know it means the potential. But I don't know what it is mathematically. There are vector operators $\vec {A} (\vec{r})$, defined using an integral (over $\vec{k}$) of linear combinations of creation and annihilation operators. But these are functions of $\vec {r}$. Then, is $\vec {A}$, like, the "total $\vec {A}$" operator, i.e. $\int \vec{A} (\vec{r} )\vec{dr}$? Or is it simply just $\vec {A} (\vec{r})$? Then isn't it weird that we're using the potential localised at a position, when the electron itself doesn't have a definite position?

**EDIT**- Ok, so $H_0+H_1$ is just a special case of $H_0+ H_1e^{i\omega t}$ with $\omega =0$. So Fermi's rule is applicable

Comment: $H_1 e^{i\omega t}$ is likely not hermitian unless $H_1$ is extremely bizarre.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero In reality, these perturbations always involve $\sin$ and $\cos$. The derivation was done with this complex Hamiltonian for simplicity

Comment: @RyderRude actually, there are very realistic situations in which the time dependence is complex (notably, cases where we drive both $x$ and $p$ and work in a rotating frame).

Comment: @DanielSank But then such an $H$ is not Hermitian?

Comment: @RyderRude oh well certainly in the typical cases we have the conjugate terms as well, but it is not always as simple as $\cos(\omega t) \hat{x}$. For example, a driven harmonic oscillator can have $H = \hbar \omega a^\dagger a - z(t) a - z(t)^* a^\dagger$ where $z(t)$ is complex.

Comment: @RyderRude It is Hermitian.